# Probability mass function (for y)

Tags: probability, statistics, generating-functions

The probability mass function of a random variable $Y$ is given by

$$f(y) = \frac{a^{(y-3)}}{(e^a)(y-3)!} \quad \text{for } y = 3,4,\dots\text{ and } a > 0$$

Derive the cumulant generating function of $Y$ and use it to obtain the kurtosis of $Y$

I think you need to use some sort of substitution to transform this into a pmf (eg $x = y - 3$) but I'm just not sure how exactly to account for the substitution.

Comment: Gamma? This is a discrete distribution. Why don't you just apply the definitions?

Comment: Thank you but i'm still confused as to how to proceed

Comment: Are you asking for the definitions or are you stuck somewhere? Please show your attempt.

Comment: I'm asking am I not supposed to use some substitution to transform this into a known distribution then derive the cgf from there?

Comment: Try the Poisson distribution.

Comment: Okay thank you I will but how does the substitution I use i.e the support of y then affect the cgf as compared to the cgf of a normal poisson?